# Conditional Comments not working in IE9 (CF environment)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, conditional-comments

Okay, I'm building a page in a CF environment. I'm testing in chrome/FF & IE9.  I'm trying to use conditional Statements for IE to deal with some minor formatting issues.

http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/5108/chromvie.png
(reverse the chrome/IE tags and I cannot put the image in the question as I just signed up today, sorry.)

My code:

```
    <!--[if gte IE 10]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ieonly.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
```

I'm able to go directly the ieonly.css page. I'm at an utter loss. I've looked at some of the other conditional comment threads and haven't been able to resolve my issue with the information. Is it because of the ColdFusion environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[if gte IE 10]` is greater than or equal to IE 10. IE 9 is less than IE 10.

Comment: I had previously been using !IE but it had not been working either, infact Chrome was displaying the changes in the stylesheet while Ie wasn't.

Comment: I changed it to look for 7 and above and it's (ofcourse) solved but chrome is no long displaying incorrectly, I must have done something dumb, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments [only work in IE 5 through 9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx), so `gte IE 10` or `gte IE 11` won't apply to anything at all.