# If ie conditional tag not working in ie9?

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-statements

Im making a website and I want a diffrent stylesheet for ie.
On ie 8 its working perfect, but ie9 just don't seem to get it.

i tried several statements, like

```
if lte IE 10
```

or

```
if IE
```

or

```
if IE 9
```

And now i found in this question: [Conditional Comments not working in IE9 (CF environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878961/conditional-comments-not-working-in-ie9-cf-environment)

tha following wich is also not working

```
if gte IE 7
```

I just don't know that I'm doing wrong the statement is correct because it does work in ie8..

the full statement is:

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
<link href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the same but w/o CC comment (i.e. insert link tag without wrapping in CC).

Probably your problem is in MIME-type received from server (IE9 bug).

Comment: Right. That happens because your server send wrong MIME-type of CSS file. It's a bug in IE9. IE9 doesn't recognize mime even if its set in type property. You have to set up right mime type in your server settings. If it's Apache, add to .htaccess following string (w/o quoting signs) "AddType text/css .css"